# Is there a way to set a socket option to indicate which VRF to use?

Tags: c, networking, tcp

I am opening a connection and want the socket to not use the default VRF but a specific VRF name or id.

Is there a sock opt which I can set when I accept a connection or is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I struggled with this in the past, that was kernel 2.6, and it had no support for this feature to the best of my knowledge. I haven't kept up to date with it since, but you may find this patch: http://sourceforge.net/p/linux-vrf/patches/1/ useful

Comment: You might add the OS. First commented assumed Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Applications that are to work within a VRF need to bind their socket to the
VRF device:

```
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, dev, strlen(dev)+1);
```

or to specify the output device using cmsg and IP_PKTINFO.

By default the scope of the port bindings for unbound sockets is
limited to the default VRF. That is, it will not be matched by packets
arriving on interfaces enslaved to an l3mdev and processes may bind to
the same port if they bind to an l3mdev.

TCP & UDP services running in the default VRF context (ie., not bound
to any VRF device) can work across all VRF domains by enabling the
tcp_l3mdev_accept and udp_l3mdev_accept sysctl options:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_l3mdev_accept=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.udp_l3mdev_accept=1
```

These options are disabled by default so that a socket in a VRF is only
selected for packets in that VRF. There is a similar option for RAW
sockets, which is enabled by default for reasons of backwards compatibility.
This is so as to specify the output device with cmsg and IP_PKTINFO, but
using a socket not bound to the corresponding VRF. This allows e.g. older ping
implementations to be run with specifying the device but without executing it
in the VRF. This option can be disabled so that packets received in a VRF
context are only handled by a raw socket bound to the VRF, and packets in the
default VRF are only handled by a socket not bound to any VRF:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.raw_l3mdev_accept=0
```

netfilter rules on the VRF device can be used to limit access to services
running in the default VRF context as well.